# CountVectorizer, using same vocabulary in a second time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here my dataset:

```
anger,happy food food
anger,dog food food
disgust,food happy food
disgust,food dog food
neutral,food food happy
neutral,food food dog
```

Second, this is my code, where I perform a bag of words using CountVectorizer class.

```
classValues =  {'anger':    '0',
            'disgust':  '1',
            'fear':     '2',
            'happiness':'3',
            'sadness':  '4',
            'surprise': '5',
            'neutral':  '6'}

def getClass(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    return float(classValues[parts[0]])

def getTags(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    return parts[1].split(" ")

conf= SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("NaiveBaye")
conf.set('spark.driver.memory','6g')
conf.set('spark.executor.memory','6g')
conf.set('spark.cores.max',156)

sc = SparkContext(conf= conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data = sc.textFile('dataset.txt')

classes = data.map(getClass).collect()
tags = data.map(getTags).collect()

d = {
    'tags' : tags,
    'classes' : classes
}

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data=d))
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="tags", outputCol="vectors")
model = cv.fit(df)
model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)

vocabulary =  sorted(map(str, model.vocabulary))
print vocabulary
```

As you can see here: `model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)` and `print vocabulary` works perfectly.

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|classes|tags               |vectors            |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|0.0    |[happy, food, food]|(3,[0,1],[2.0,1.0])|
|0.0    |[dog, food, food]  |(3,[0,2],[2.0,1.0])|
|1.0    |[food, happy, food]|(3,[0,1],[2.0,1.0])|
|1.0    |[food, dog, food]  |(3,[0,2],[2.0,1.0])|
|6.0    |[food, food, happy]|(3,[0,1],[2.0,1.0])|
|6.0    |[food, food, dog]  |(3,[0,2],[2.0,1.0])|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
['dog', 'food', 'happy']
```

Now, if I want in a second time, perform a vectorizer of a new element using the same vocabulary how can I do this in python?

For example

```
anger, happy dog food
```

will be

```
|0.0    |[happy, dog, food]|(3,[0,1, 2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
```

I've read in the documentation that exist CountVectorizerModel that permit load an exist vocabulary. But there's not any documantation about this.

This is very important to me because if I need to classify a new element I need the same order of the vectors, in order to use the same model of my classificator.

I've tried somethings like this:

```
CountVectorizerModel(vocabulary)
```

but doesn't work.

### Edit 1

I'm currently using **Spark 1.6.1**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. CountVectorizer extract vocabulary and create the CountVectorizerModel in which you have the vocabulary. Where did you read that you can load a existing vocabulary ? You want to persist your model ? Is that the question ?

Comment: @eliasah exactly! This model I will pass to a NaiveBayes for training. 
In a second moment, I need to classify other element. 
So I need to use the same model in order to work!

Comment: I've answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

From **spark 2.0**, it's available in `pyspark`, and it is like persisting and load other `spark-ml` models.

Ok let's first create a model :

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel

# Input data: Each row is a bag of words with a ID.
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a b c".split(" ")),
    (1, "a b b c a".split(" "))
], ["id", "words"])

# fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus.
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="features", vocabSize=3, minDF=2.0)

model = cv.fit(df)

result = model.transform(df)
result.show(truncate=False)
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
# |id |words          |features                 |
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
# |0  |[a, b, c]      |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
# |1  |[a, b, b, c, a]|(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
```

then persist it :

```
model.save("/tmp/count_vec_model")
```

now you can load it and use it :

```
same_model = CountVectorizerModel.load("/tmp/count_vec_model")
same_model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
# |id |words          |features                 |
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
# |0  |[a, b, c]      |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
# |1  |[a, b, b, c, a]|(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
# +---+---------------+-------------------------+
```

For more information, please refer to the following documentation concerning [Saving and loading spark-ml models/pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-pipeline.html#saving-and-loading-pipelines).

The model creation code example is available in the official documentation.

Comment: I've tried.  `model.save("/tmp/count_vec_model")` say: `AttributeError: 'CountVectorizerModel' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using ? :-/

Comment: @Steve for future use, including the Spark version in your OP is always a good idea, especially if you are using a somewhat older version. For some good guidelines in asking, see [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples)

Comment: @desertnaut Ok, I'll update my question to be more specific!

Comment: @desertnaut A monkey patch can be done to solve this but I don't have time to write it and test it :/